# Is there a way to mitigate IndexInHeapMap initialization during boost dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: c++, boost, dijkstra, path-finding, boost-graph

*Context:* My code use boost dijkstra algorithm to perform pathfinding on 13.4M vertices/33M edges graph. While doing profiling, I notice that 60% of dijkstra calls were dominated by a call that initialize a `IndexInHeapMap` during `dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map_no_init`. I suspect that it take so long because of the graph size

**Is there a way to avoid/reduce this initialization cost ?**

Maybe it worst to note that our dijkstra call are capped and does not perform a lot of iterations compared to the graph size

I looked at [boost source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map.hpp), and saw that at some point, a macro allowed to use an alternative queue (`BOOST_GRAPH_DIJKSTRA_USE_RELAXED_HEAP`). But I couldn't find documentation about it, and it seems that this part was removed in [more recent version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map.hpp) (we use v1.62)

My exact call to boost dijkstra is

```
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_color_map_no_init(
      graph,
      sourceVertex,
      &(predecessors[0]),
      &(distances[0]),
      weights,
      vertexIndex,
      std::less<uint32_t>(),
      boost::closed_plus<uint32_t>(),
      infinity,
      zero,
      visitor
);
```

And then inside boost code, it become very long in this area

```
    typedef
      detail::vertex_property_map_generator<Graph, VertexIndexMap, std::size_t>
      IndexInHeapMapHelper;
    typedef typename IndexInHeapMapHelper::type IndexInHeapMap;
    typedef
      d_ary_heap_indirect<Vertex, 4, IndexInHeapMap, DistanceMap, DistanceCompare>
      VertexQueue;
  
    boost::scoped_array<std::size_t> index_in_heap_map_holder;
    IndexInHeapMap index_in_heap =
      IndexInHeapMapHelper::build(graph, index_map, // <--- Take 60% of scope runtime
                                  index_in_heap_map_holder);  
    VertexQueue vertex_queue(distance_map, index_in_heap, distance_compare);
```

Comment: Each time you call dijkstra's, it allocates a new contiguous array that  has storage for every vertex. In your case, a lot! I don't see any customization point for you to control this behavior; you may be able to hack the source up so that you can re-use the same array if you find yourself making multiple calls  on the same graph.

Comment: That is a BIG graph.  I would be interested to know what performance you get.  My code on a 0.4M node and 3M link graph needs 7 minutes to find the shortest path from a node to every other node.  Details at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/wiki/Performance

Comment: @AndyG yes i though about this as a last solution. I'm not so into working with a custom boost version and all the inconvenience that come with it

Comment: @ravenspoint unfortunately my visitor is not set up to perform a full graph dijkstra right now. Anyway, my graph is made of 9 disconnected components. And as I right this I'm wondering if I could reduce the initialization cost by using some kind of graph view to use only the component where the source vertex is..

Comment: Is your graph available for download somewhere?

Comment: no. But even if that would be the case, that would be hard to use it without the code because its a boost::graph::adjacency_list with custom vertex and edge. It is created by parsing OSM data of France (+ DOM-TOM) and a few other countries

Comment: To create space delimited text file of all your edges: for (auto ed : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
    cout << (int) source(ed, g) <<" " << (int) target(ed, g)) << "\n"
}